# Find the asymptotes of the Folium of Descartes ($x^3+y^3-3xy=0$)

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the asymptotes of the Folium of Descartes, which has the equation $$x^3+y^3-3xy=0$$

I was also told to find the curve length in the first quadrant, and to do so I parametrized it by finding the intersection between the curve and the line $y=tx$. The parametric equation is $$(x, y) = (\frac{3t}{1+t^3},\frac{3t^2}{1+t^3})$$

There is an invalid $t$ value, which is $t=-1$, which looks to be about the slope of the asymptotes on the graph. However, I'm not sure how to obtain this value with calculus instead of guessing. I have one way, but it feels really hacky. Differentiating implicitly, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2-y}{x-y^2}$$

Assuming that $x$ and $y$ approach $\infty$ at the same rate, the equation simplifies to $-1$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2-y}{x-y^2} \implies \lim_{x,y\to\infty}\frac{dy}{dx} \approx \frac{x}{-y}=-1$$

But how can I be sure that that assumption is correct? Am I allowed to reason that, since the equation of the folium appears symmetrical for both $y$ and $x$ (i.e. if I replace $x$ with $y$ and vice versa I get the same equation), $x$ and $y$ approach $\infty$ at the same speed? This assumption also feels gimmicky—is there a better way?

Even after I find the slope, I'm not sure how to find the line, in form $y=mx+b$.

Comment: Find the equation of the curve in polar coordinates.  You'll find $r$ goes to $\infty$ exactly when $\cos\theta+\sin\theta=0$.

Comment: In your parametric equation, calculate $x+y$.  You should find $t+1$ cancels, then you can set $t=-1$.

Comment: @Michael, I got the correct answer ($x+y=-1$) using your method, but how do you know that's an asymptote?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I set $y=ax+b$ in my equation and ended up with $$(1+a^3)x^3 + (3a^2b-3a)x^2+(3ab^2-3b)x+b^3=0$$ I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: There's nothing hacky with accepting that when the intersection of the curve and the line goes to infinity you have an asymptote. This only gives you the direction, but not the intercept, and you can assume a form $y+x=c$.

Comment: Look in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Algebraic_curves).

Comment: Ones you've set $y=ax+b$ and you get the equation $(1+a^3)x^{3}+(3a^{2}b-3a)x^{2}+(3ab^{2}-3b)x+b^{3}=0$ you have to equal the coefficients of degree two and three equal to zero, so $$1+a^3=0 \iff a=-1$$ and $$3a^{2}b-3a=0 \iff b=-1$$ hence you get an asymptote at $y=-x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that in your parametrization
$$ x+y+1 = \frac{3t}{1+t^3} + \frac{3t^2}{1+t^3}+1 = \frac{(1+t)^2}{1-t+t^2}$$

so $x+y+1=0$ is the asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to recall that:
$$ x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = (x+y+z)\cdot\frac{(x-y)^2+(x-z)^2+(y-z)^2}{2}$$
hence the Descartes folium is the [blowup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up) of a conic and a line, and $x+y+1=0$ is an asymptote.

Comment: How do you learn this kind of thing?